# IE8 - Scroll nav not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I am confused as to why the main nav on this site does not work in IE8.

*removed*

As you can see the code for the nav is very simple, with a localScroll attached to it for the scrolling effect.

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#top"  class="scroller nav-active">PLAY</a></li>
     <li><a href="#top1" class="scroller">PRACTICE</a></li>
     <li><a href="#top2" class="scroller">LEARN</a></li>
     <li><a href="#top3" class="scroller">DINE</a></li>
     <li><a href="#top4" class="scroller">JOIN</a></li>
     <li><a href="#top5" class="scroller">ABOUT</a></li>
 </ul>

 $('.nav, .section2_blog2_right, .logo').localScroll({
            offset: {left: 0, top: -50},
            duration: 2000
        });
```

Comment: This guy seemed to have the same problem. Using 1.6.2 seemed to solve it for him, if that's an option for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320173/

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the localScroll / jquery though. If I comment out the localScroll code, the main nav still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just figured this out.  It seems to have been the filter: in the CSS that loads for IE8 and below.  I removed it and I can now click on the main nav links.